# Access methods to jquery plugins without variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, flot

I will take an example of the thing I can not do using `flot chart` plugin, but I think it's the same behaviour for all jQuery plugins.

`Flot chart` is a jquery plugin for charts displaying. You invoke it with

```
$('#graph').plot(data);
```

The documentation says you have access to a lot of methods, like this:

```
var plot = $('#graph').plot(data);
plot.getAxes();
```

The thing is I'm in a situation where the `plot` variable is not defined, so I can no write `plot.getAxes()`. I tried some dummy methods, like `$('#graph').plot().getAxes()` (removing all the data) or `$('#graph').plot.getAxes()` (undefined method).

Is there a method to access `plot` plugins methods through `$('#graph')` selector ?

Comment: use like `$('#graph').data('plot').getAxes()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `plot` variable later:

```
var plot = $('#graph').data('plot');
plot.getAxes();
```

or use it directly like this:

```
$('#graph').data('plot').getAxes();
```

Which is descibed in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#introduction).

Comment: Is it a "standard" method for most jquery plugins ? or specific to flot ?

Comment: I don't know of any other jquery plugin which does it like that but I don't know a lot of them.

Comment: Thanks @Raidri ... The `data` seems to be a "best practice".